# Submit custom form on plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem on make a custom form plugin action on a second page.

I have a plugin folder name demo1 with two different page like `alert.php` and `demo1.php`

I included a form on `demo1.php` and I want to process this form on `alert.php` where the database insert query has been declared.

Here is the code

`demo1.php`

```
function alert_options() 
{
    echo '<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Alert</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_admin_url()."admin-post.php"; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit-form" />    
         <input type="hidden" name="title" value="test" />
         <input type="hidden" name="content" value="test" />
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Alert" /></p>
    </form>
    </div>';
}
```

`alert.php`

```
add_action('admin_post_submit-form', '_handle_form_action');
function _handle_form_action()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $content=$_POST['content'];
    $data=array('title'=>$title,'content'=>$content);
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_alerts', $data);         
}
```

Comment: please give a quick response

Comment: the question is not clear .. what is the output needed .??

Comment: Hi , whenever i want submit the form it goes to http://localhost/test/Demo/wp-admin/admin-post.php  this link and shows blank but here insert query should work with post data

Comment: Hi Rupam, you want to call the alert_options() function from alert.php right ?

Comment: Hi Ganapathy, 
No, i have a declared a form on alert_options() which has in demo1.php and i want to submit the form with action alert.php where the insert query has been declared.

Comment: Hi Ganapathy and anuraj, if you didn't understand please inform me because i am hungry to know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing correct,

include the alert.php file path on demo1.php

like this..

demo1.php

```
<?php 
// Include alert.php file
include_once 'alert.php';

function alert_options() { ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Alert</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_admin_url()."admin-post.php"; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit-form" />
         <input type="hidden" name="title" value="test" />
         <input type="hidden" name="content" value="test" />
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Alert" /></p>

    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

alert.php

```
<?php
add_action('admin_post_submit-form', '_handle_form_action');
function _handle_form_action(){
    global $wpdb;
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $content=$_POST['content'];
    $data=array('title'=>$title,'content'=>$content);
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_alerts', $data);

    // redirect after insert alert
    wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=test-url'));
    die();


}
```

Comment: @Rupam ... Glad to help.. That is what you wanted?